# javascript: factor if statement

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am wondering how to factor multiple boolean like that:

```
itemA = false;
itemB = false;
itemC = false;

switchMenu(id: string) {
 if (id === 'a') {
  this.itemA = true;
  this.itemB = false;
  this.itemC = false;

 } else if(id === 'b') {
  this.itemA = false;
  this.itemB = true;
  this.itemC = false;
} else if(id === 'c') {
  this.itemA = false;
  this.itemB = false;
  this.itemC = true;
}
}
```

the main goal is to switch on menu item on click. Also I want to put itemA, itemB and itemC in a literal object to write better code

Answer (score 4):

## Simple Approach

I would probably do something like:

```
this.itemA = id === 'a';
this.itemB = id === 'b';
this.itemC = id === 'c';
```

You can avoid the if statements entirely by just setting each boolean as to the result of the comparison with the constant.

---

## Dynamic Approach

Or you make your items more like:

```
items = { a: true, b: false, c: false }
```

And now the `id`'s are the same as the keys of that object. That means you could do:

```
class MyClass {
    items = { a: true, b: false, c: false }

    switchMenu(id: keyof MyClass['items']) {
        const keys = Object.keys(this.items) as Array<keyof MyClass['items']>
        keys.forEach(key => this.items[key] = key === id)
    }
}

// Elsewhere
const myInstance = new MyClass()
if (myInstance.items.a) { /* show A menu */ }
if (myInstance.items.b) { /* show B menu */ }
if (myInstance.items.c) { /* show C menu */ }
```

In this case, you iterate over the keys of the `items` object setting each value to `true` if it's a match. This is handy because you don't need to manually change the `switchMenu` method if you add a new item.

Just note the `as Array<keyof MyClass['items']>`. `Object.keys()` sadly just returns `string[]`, because Typescript is being a bit paranoid about the fact there may be keys at runtime that are not part of the type here. So the cast tells Typescript that `keys` are, in fact, the exact keys that can be used to index this object.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=4&ts=4.5.0-beta&ssl=16&ssc=46&pln=12&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsByBDB0C8UDkLtQB8cAjfI7AY2wChqKAbFAZyagFkQBhRlqAb2pQhUAJbwErLHygoAXFGAAnAK4QANFGLyAZinpN1UCjr0GoAX1rCoTAO5iKACzYQAdsoAUIgCbyA1hAgAPba7Fw8TADa2GKITNgAugCU-ILWwhRBrkzAUAEgklAA8sQAVhAUwAB0+UwewI4iTFWxEinMUACCioooIAA8+SFh3MxRMeLxCQB8ael5gc3aQYoAoihOHvlQGNMKjc2tUfkJOwsgOxhYPklzFtSW1AD0T1Cr+hC2jhCKEHRZOSgCBAMGywBQrgomCgrk+IwiHluIlCHmBoJyEKhLUmVRQKWkTwAVDZHEFbF0gW5lFBCa9LMioKiQWDMRBsXEqsR8VAiSSyVAAEKU9w0unUBlM9HgyFso5VCjc3lMUnkzjC6m0ixAA)

Depending on your goals here, this approach may be overkill. I'd go with the first one unless you plan to change this list a lot and it has a lot of entries.

---

## A Totally Different Approach with Less Code

Lastly, this above may be the wrong approach entirely! If you have a dictionary of booleans where only *one* can be true, then a simple selected value may be better.

```
type ItemName = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'

class MyClass {
    selectedItemName: ItemName = 'a'

    switchMenu(id: ItemName) {
        this.selectedItemName = id
    }
}

// Elsewhere
const myInstance = new MyClass()
if (myInstance.selectedItemName === 'a') { /* show A menu */ }
if (myInstance.selectedItemName === 'b') { /* show B menu */ }
if (myInstance.selectedItemName === 'c') { /* show C menu */ }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=4&ts=4.5.0-beta&ssl=15&ssc=63&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsByBDB0C8UDkLtQB8cAjfI7AY2wChqKAbFAZyagFkQBhRlqAb2pQhUJhHoQK8ACZxEqdAC5Y8ZGkw48tYSIDuAS2AUAFmwgA7AK4AKPVKWzV6AJT9B24cCN6mAOlHjJCBkVeXVbNyEAX2po6gB6OKgAUXpRHSMIACcIOgB7MyZgKAQQGALgFDMKdTMIHXYuHiYrJ2o9ADMoKxKywsrqvzEJaQdQqAwJjWwXPig4gCoRI1z6gEFi8wsoecTojq6e8v6IQYCRkLVxyexSGbnFpmX6gCENy23dts7u0qOqk-8wyCo0uEywlGm-HuSxWUE4by2OygkSAA)

Comment: Thanks I was literally looking for a tips like the third one with less code